# Angular 6 error call function from expression

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular 6 applicaiton. I try to call a method from an expression. Unfortunately it seems it doesn't work anymore.

The example is very simple and looks like that in my **car.component.html**:

```
<div>Car Name: {{ getCarName() }} </div>
```

In my component code **car.component.ts**, I implemented that function something like that:

```
getCarName() {
  return this.carName;
}
```

*Actually I'm changing the property `carName` each time I hover over another div on my component UI.*

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value...**

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thank you!!

Comment: you can put in your html <div>Car Name: {{ carName }} </div>, have you tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError** means, that if you construct your logic this way, you have to detect changes manually inside your component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

/* Other stuff goes here */

export class PhoneVerifyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    /* This way the detector will run after every change */
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  getCarName() {
    /* This way you run detector only on this function call */
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    return this.carName;
  }
}
```

You can choose every way you like, run detector in specific place, or after every change. If your goal is just to solve the issue only with this method, I recommend to run it on specific function call, but if you have many cases like that - better run it in `ngAfterViewChecked`.

**BUT**

The shortest way is to store the result of this function execution to class property and simply interpolate this property, instead of method:

```
<div>Car Name: {{ carName }}</div>
```

Anyway, we don't know your goals and what's going on in your real project, so you have to choose more proper way for your case.